# Passing a NSString to another ViewController using classes

Tags: objective-c, ios, class, nsstring

I know this insanely simple, but I am re-teaching myself the basics and trying to get my head around this:-)

I have one ViewController called MainVC and I have one called ClassVC

In ClassVC I have this code:

```
@interface ClassVC : UIViewController
{
   NSString *mainLine;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mainLine;
@end
```

and I have this in the implementation file:

```
@synthesize mainLine = _mainLine;

-(NSString *)_mainLine
{
    _mainLine = @"This a string from a Class";
    return _mainLine;
}
```

Now I was thinking that if I #import the ClassVC into MainVC I would be able to transfer that string along as well like so:

```
 This code is in the viewDidLoad

    _mainLabel.text = _secondClass.mainLine;

    NSLog(@"%@", _secondClass.mainLine);
```

But that is not working - so cannot I not pass strings in through this way???

Comment: what is _secondClass?  How do you define that?

Comment: _secondClass is ClassVc sorry forgot to mention that

Comment: Where do you create the _secondClass? Can you post the code?

Comment: Totally eliminate the _mainLine method.  Instead, init the _mainLine variable in the ClassVC `init` method.

Comment: Silly question:  Is _secondClass pointing to anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your property is mainLine, so the overridden getter should be -(NSString *)mainLine not -(NSString *)_mainLine.

```
-(NSString *)mainLine
{
    _mainLine = @"This a string from a Class";
    return _mainLine;
}
```

This worked for me.  In the ClassVC:

```
@interface ClassVC : UIViewController 

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *mainLine;

@end


#import "ClassVC.h"

@implementation ClassVC

-(NSString *)mainLine
{
    _mainLine = @"This a string from a Class";
    return _mainLine;
}
```

And this in ViewController:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>
@class ClassVC;

@interface ViewController : UIViewController

@property (strong,nonatomic) ClassVC *secondClass;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *mainLabel;
@end

#import "ViewController.h"
#import "ClassVC.h"

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    ClassVC *secondClass = [[ClassVC alloc] init];
    self.mainLabel.text = secondClass.mainLine;
     NSLog(@"%@", secondClass.mainLine);
}
```

Comment: @JeffKranenburg -- It's probably time to learn how to use the debugger.

Comment: @JeffKranenburg, I tried it and it worked fine. See my edited answer for what I did.

Comment: yeah going to look into that now:-) @rdelmar this could be just me not seeing it, but is the class in the header not irrelevant since I am importing it in the implementation file again?

Comment: If you mean the @class statement, no, it's needed because I declare a property of type ClassVC, and the compiler needs to know that that class exists.

Answer (score 0):

The line:

```
@synthesize mainLine = _mainLine;
```

means create a getter and setter methods called `mainLine` and `setMainLine:` respectively, that wrap an instance variable named `_mainLine`. (It creates the instance variable for you so the instance variable `mainLine` you've declare in the header is not needed)

(The name before the = is the property name, the name after the equals is the name of the ivar it wraps)

You have tried to override the getter but used the name of the instance variable. The getter doesn't start with an underscore so remove the underscore from the method that returns the string.

So in your `viewDidLoad` method you are calling the `mainLine` method which just returns the `_mainLine` instance variable. Your `_mainLine` method is never called

If you are just returning a constant string then you don't need the property and ivar at all.

(Also you shouldn't start method names or variables with underscores, as the underscore means by convention it is private and Apple basically reserved all method names starting with an underscore. However it is common to have ivars start with underscores)